# Complex calculations for an interactive table in a R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

Most shiny examples are very easy to reproduce. But as I am not R expert, it is hard for me to enhance them for more complex ideas. In the following, I invented an example that represents my problem (which is a lot more complex). If you want to reproduce it, you need to add chunk labels for each code snippet.

title: "Test"

author: "Test Person"

date: "3/17/2021"

output: html_document

runtime: shiny

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

My example-dataframe:

```
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=4))
colnames(mydata) <- c("player","time","routelength")
mydata$player <- c(1,2,3,4)
mydata$time <- c(20,30,10,20)
mydata$routelength <- c(200,350,410,220)
```

Shiny UI with a Slider:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("multi", label = "Choose:",
              min = 1, max = 10, value = 1),
  tableOutput("data"),
)
```

Shiny server & Shiny App:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    mydata$routelength*input$multi
    mydata
        })
  output$data <- renderTable({sliderValues()}, bordered=TRUE, digits=5)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I do it this way, the result is a static table with no changes when using the slider. If I change it to:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    mydata$routelength*input$multi
        })
  output$data <- renderTable({sliderValues()}, bordered=TRUE, digits=5)
}
```

then there is only one column which is reacting.

But what I would like to have is the rendering of the WHOLE table with column "routelength" that reacts on the slider changes.

In my real R file, the problem is much more complex: I have a lot of calculations (hundreds of code lines) which depend on my sliderinput (I call them via `<<rchunklable>>`) and in the end there is a resulting table I would like to visualize. I have no idea HOW to include all these calculations... without shiny my code is working... but with shiny it is not. The example above which consists only of one calculation is only a representation of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define the data as `reactive`. Try this :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("multi", label = "Choose:",
              min = 1, max = 10, value = 1),
  tableOutput("data"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderTable({
    mydata$routelength <- mydata$routelength*input$multi
    mydata
    }, bordered=TRUE, digits=5)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! When do I need `reactive` instead?

Comment: This will still work with `reactive` as well. I usually use `reactive` only when I have to use data in different parts of the application.